# Datepicker codeigniter - PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, datepicker

I want to make a date picker where the user will be able to modify the data inside the date field within my query.

This is what I have:

Every time that I click on USER button in the main page it "runs" this:

```
href="<?php echo site_url('MAIN/user_data') ?>"
```

Then, it executes this:

```
    public function user_data(){

            $data['records']=$this->model_1->getINFOUSER();
            $this->load->view('info_user',$data);
        }
```

Finally, this is the function **getINFOUSER**

```
public function getINFOUSER(){

$query = $this->db->query("select * from users where created_at >= '2019-02-10'");
if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
    $result= $query->result_array();
}

return $result;
```

I want the user to be able to modify the field **created_at** in the beginning.

I was thinking about something like this:

> $query = $this->db->query("select * from users where created_at >=
>   '$variable'");

```
<form method="post"> <p> Select Date:<input id="datepicker"
 type="text" size="8" name="datepicker"/> </p> <input type="submit"
 value="Submit" name="usub"/> </form>
```

But I am pretty lost. Could you please help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass the selected date to the query, you have to collect the submitted data(here date) from the controller function then you have to pass it to model function. From there you can replace the static date(date you manually added) with the dynamic data(date) you got in model.

For posting form data to controller, you have to specify the function to be executed after submitting the form in `action` attribute of `<form>`.

**Change the `HTML` code as below.**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('MAIN/user_data') ?>">
    <p> Select Date:<input id="datepicker" type="text" size="8" name="datepicker"/></p> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="usub"/>
</form>
```

**Change the controller function as below.**

```
public function user_data(){
    $date_created=$_POST['datepicker'];//Collecting submitted date
    $data['records']=$this->model_1->getINFOUSER($date_created);//Calling model function by passing the date submitted
    $this->load->view('info_user',$data);
}
```

**Change the model function as below.**

```
public function getINFOUSER($date){
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from users where created_at >='".$date."'");
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        $result= $query->result_array();
    }
    return $result;
}
```